# HtmlAgilityPack gethtmlweb.load(Links[i]) can't load the link from the list

Tags: asp.net

I am getting confused by passing the a static link to getHtmlWeb.Load("www.daraz.pk/laptops") which works correctly 
But when i try to pass it an element from the list it does not work.

Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < Links.Count; i++)
{
       OutputLabel.Text += Links[i] + "<br/>";
       int i = 0;
       var getHtmlWeb1 = new HtmlWeb();
       OutputLabel.Text += link11 + "<br/>";
       var doc = getHtmlWeb1.Load(Links[i]);
       var desc = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id='productDescriptionTab']/div/h3[1]");
       if (desc != null)
       {
           foreach (var d in desc)
           {
               OutputLabel.Text += d.InnerText + "<br/>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            OutputLabel.Text += "Oopss I am Broken!!";
        }
  }
```

Comment: This is going to have something to do with the html you loaded. Can you post the relevant section of the html?

Comment: string link = "https://www.daraz.pk/laptops/";     
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(link);
var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='sku -gallery']/a");
foreach (var aTag in aTags)
{
   string link1 = aTag.Attributes["href"].Value;
}

Comment: <h3 style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: inherit; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.2; color: inherit; margin: 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 15px; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; padding: 0px;">Display</h3>

Xpath = //*[@id='productDescriptionTab']/div/h3[1]"

Comment: sir there is nothing to do with html i 've loaded the problem is only in the code statement var getHtmlWeb.Load(string); this thing takes a string as a parameter but i am passing a string list to it which is not working. like 'var doc = getHtmlWeb.Load(Links[i]);' @MatthewMartin